# GIT getting to an older version and back to the under-development one

Tags: git, git-stash

**What I want to do** : I am working with a code using git versioning. I realized that some tests were not run with an older version of the code (2 commits before on the same branch). So I want to run those tests which requires modifying some git-followed input files and after I want to get back to my under-development version as if nothing happened (not taking care about the changes made in the input files since I do not care about these changes).

**What I did** : I git stash my underdev version and then git checkout to the older version. I modified a few files and made the runs. Then comes the problem : When I git stash apply I did not get back to my underdev version (I thought I would). I remained in a detached head state at the older version.

Fortunately I noted the id of the underdev version so I think that I can checkout to get back there. But, can anyone explain me what I did wrong and how I can do what I want in a clean way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your underdev is two things:

- a commit history
- unstaged changes

You've saved the unstaged changes using git stash.

To get back to your underdev version, you need to checkout to the branch you were when you stashed it.

You can find that information in `git stash show`.

Here's your workflow:

```
git stash
git checkout OLD_COMMIT
*do some work*
#Throw the changes away
git checkout .
git checkout UNDERDEV_BRANCH
git stash pop
```

Comment: The `stash pop` here may be risky because if re-applying the patch messes up that work could be lost. For the OP's situation, using `stash apply` may be a little safer...

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink A stash that was made on the exact the same code has no reason not to apply. But yeah, if you want to be super safe, you could use `stash apply` and then `stash drop`.

Comment: Good point on applying a stash on the same code in which it was originally stashed upon having no chance of a conflict. Just a safety precaution when still getting up-to-speed with Git workflows

Comment: Well, when I 'git checkout UNDERDEV_BRANCH', git tell me that "the following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout: file_name. Please move or remove them before switcing branches. Aborting."

Comment: You can't keep the modification you've made of the older commit with you. Throw them away: `git checkout .`

Comment: @ blue112 'git checkout .' changes nothing. Still have the same error and cannot checkout to the UNDERDEV_BRANCH

Comment: Move to the root directory of your git project before issuing that command.

Comment: I am in the directory where the .git directory is.

Comment: It seems that git checkout . does not throw my changes away. However it is exactly what I want to do !

Comment: I finally rm the problem file and then succeed in getting back to the UNDERDEV_BRANCH. That's definitely not clean. Next time, I'll do as you propose and see if git checkout . works better. Thanx for your help.

Comment: Don't hesitate to mark the answer as validated if it helped you fix your problem.

Comment: Doing the same manipulation today and everything works just fine using this workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you started out on the `foo` branch.

This sentence seems to imply that you didn't get your HEAD pointer back to it's original location:

> I remained in a detached head state at the older version

So, to get out of the "detached head" state, and recover your un-committed work:

```
git checkout foo
git stash apply
```

In the future, it *may* be easier to simply commit your in-progress work on a topic branch with a workflow like this:

```
# save your work on a topic branch
git checkout -b myTopicBranch
git add .
git commit -m "wip"

# run tests on older revision
git checkout oldSha
run tests...

# ok, done, back to work
git checkout myTopicBranch
```

Then, just merge your work back to master once you have finished work on the topic branch.

Comment: No, not on the master branch ... My branch of the project.

Comment: @raoulpetite gotcha, I updated my answer to use just a generic branch as the starting point

Comment: Well, when I 'git checkout myTopicBranch, git tell me that "the following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout: file_name. Please move or remove them before switcing branches. Aborting."

Comment: @raoulpetite that means that changes were made and Git needs them to be accounted for prior to moving to the branch. If you wish to save those changes you could stash them. Or simply `rm` the untracked file if you don't need it

Comment: Well, that is exactly what I was about to do.

Comment: BTW, I understand the workflow you propose but then what's the point in git stash ? It looked like what I want to do without committing a work in an "unstable" state.

Comment: @raoulpetite I would say that stash is more for quick-n-dirty situations where one needs to check something on a different branch real quick and then go back to where they were working. Your situation qualifies for that, but when getting started with Git it's probably best to save things on a topic branch as there is less chance of accidentally losing work. Mostly a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

If you have committed every change of your underdev version and your work tree is clean, `git stash` just tells `No local changes to save`, in which case no new stash is added.

If your underdev version has a branch name, just `git checkout <branch>` can take you back. A more common way is to use `git reflog` to find the previous commits that HEAD was once referring to.